# Counter fails to register number of count

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

When someone clicks a button on my web page, this JavaScript code runs:

```
function count() {
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp(); // XMLHttpRequest object
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "count.php", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Then, this PHP script gets executed: (a common)

```
<?php

mysql_connect("host","username","password"); 
mysql_select_db('database');
mysql_query('UPDATE table SET field = field + 1'); 

?>
```

The problem may vary. Lets say I click ten times, it only registers 8 or something. Sometimes it works, other times it does not.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth This code should work perfectly fine :)

Comment: @user1431627: You're missing the point. It's deprecated. Please, for all of our sakes, read the comment thoroughly, and apply what it says.

Comment: Check your server logs, is the browser actually sending the request each time the button is clicked?  GET method requests to the same url are often served out of the browsers cache

Comment: @JoeDay Nope. It fails to log all of the requests. Is there any other options left?

Comment: I don't see a limit or a condition in that query, are you sure you want to update all rows?

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan What do you mean? Just save the count to the database?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET field = field + 1` updates *all* rows.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan It connects to the database, goes to the table, and then updates the field by adding one. This is what I found when searching for a counter in MySQL and PHP. I thought it was a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is always a solution...**

**Quick Fix Solution @**

Make Your AJAX call synchronous. Note: This will make the Generate button seem stuck during the duration of execution and I think you don't want that (as you are keeping all the names in JS array for faster loading... Yes i visited your link... thanks for posting it)

```
function count() {
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
    var async = false;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "count.php?" + Math.random, async);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

**Better Solution**

```
//call submit count every 60 secs, play with it to get a interval that suits you best
window.setTimeout("submitCount();",60000);
var globalCounter = 0;
function count() 
{
    globalCounter++;
}

function submitCount(){
    if (globalCounter > 0)
    {
        var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
        var async = false;
        var countForPHP = globalCounter;
        globalCounter = 0;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "count.php?r=" + Math.random + "&count=" + countForPHP, async);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
    window.setTimeout("submitCount();",60000);
}
```

Change your PHP to get countForPHP from Request.QueryString and update SQL accordingly

Note: Counts will be lost when the website is closed and that 60 sec lot is not committed to server. To take care of that you may want to call submitCount on window.onbeforeunload

Comment: This works, but the problem is that now the rest of the application lags. JavaScript has only one thread. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome... really, this great. I understand everything except for the countForPHP and stuff. What do you mean?

Comment: Or, wait. What if I use the first solution and use WebWorkers, WebSocket or Comet for that?

Comment: countForPHP is a variable appending to your query string to transfer globalCounter value from client to Server.

Comment: You may also use any AJAX queuing procedure to achieve your goal but with using the setTimeout procedure you will save on several HTTP Requests.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15485/discussion-between-user961954-and-user1431627)

Answer (score 3):

You want to disable the button for clicking until the Ajax request is complete and a success message was returned. For instance, check the commenting mechanism here on StackOverflow. You can't press it twice, because after the first time it gets disabled.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tests", "user", "pass");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    //Have PDO throw exceptions on errors. That way you don't miss 'em.
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `field` = `field`+1";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    //In case an error has occurred, it will be caught and handled here.
    die("There was an error with the database! " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

That is how I would have done it in PDO.

Comment: @user1431627: That's where the power of PDO and transactions come into play.

Comment: @user1431627: Might. It would still be better for user experience if you disabled the button and showed them the request is being processed.

Comment: @Truth I did this after what I read on the Wiki:

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx;', 'xxx', 'xxx');
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_click SET click = click + 1";
$pdo->($sql);

It works. But the same problem occurs. How does Facebook do this?

Comment: @Truth The page is http://rawnhansen.com/ng - as you can see from obivious reasons.. it cannot be done.

Comment: Here is a place where you can see the count http://rawnhansen.com/ng/stats.php - But I have to accept the fact that it's not possible now, but maybe in the future. I have to live with it. Thanks for everything - accepted answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the browser loading the result from the cache.  Add code to send headers to disable caching of the page when you respond in count.php (from php.net header example):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Comment: This is a problem with JavaScript? Too many XMLHttpRequests at a time.

Comment: No, XMLHttpRequest will hit the browser's local cache instead of submitting to the server if the local cache is still valid.  Those headers on the counter's response will make sure the browser never caches the response, so every request will be sent to the server.

Comment: I did it. But the problem is still there. There is no options left other than living with it.

Answer (score 0):

Store individual click (with datetime) in the database instead of updating the field. For that, your count.php need to be changed to insert a record(for one click) into the table.

To get the total no. of clicks, you can use "count(1)" of the table. Since you are inserting the date and time of click, you can get the day/week/month/year wise data clicks from the table.

BTW, UPDATE will lock the record/row while updating it. When more than 1 requests are trying to update the same record at the same time (in case of concurrent requests), update may fail because of locking issue.

Your table(clicks - table name) can be as below.
`+-------------+---------------------+`
`| sourceip    | click_date          |`
`+-------------+---------------------+`
`| 10.32.12.45 | 2012-08-16 13:35:03 |`
`+-------------+---------------------+`
And the query in count.php should be like 
insert into clicks(sourceip, click_date) values('10.32.12.45', now());

You can get the source ip (client ip) using php script.

And the below queries give you the no. of clicks per day/month/year.
Day => select date_format(click_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, count(1) clicks from clicks group by date_format(click_date, '%Y-%m-%d');
Month => select date_format(click_date, '%Y-%m') as date, count(1) clicks from clicks group by date_format(click_date, '%Y-%m');
Year => select date_format(click_date, '%Y') as date, count(1) clicks from clicks group by date_format(click_date, '%Y');

Answer (score -1):

Try This Out:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password"); 
mysql_select_db('database', $con);

$result = mysql_query("select * from table");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numrows!=0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)){
        $Field = $row['field'];
    }
$FieldTwo = $Field+1;
$result = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET field='$FieldTwo'); 

}
```

Comment: @Radu This is because of JavaScript :(

Comment: @Radu I did a little PDO code in user Truth's answer. I did what was in the Wiki. It still has the counting problem. I don't know how Facebook manages to do this...

Comment: @Radu Maybe they are using Web Worker/async?